# List Items not working

Tags: java, android

I made a simple list which calls other activities when a ListItem is clicked, but it is not working for me. When I click, nothing shows up. WHat is wrong ? Here is the code:

```
    String classes[]={"StartingPoint","Splash", "ex1","ex2"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try
    {

        Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.alfred.splashscreenwithsound." + cheese);
        Intent myintent = new Intent(this,ourclass);
        startActivity(myintent);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'd first try simplifying the startActivity call like this:
`startActivity(new Intent(originatingclassname.this, targetclassname.class));`

Comment: change the catch case to Log.e("YourTag","Stacktrace", e); and tell us whether there is a stacktrace printed in the log. Are your classes/cheese written correctly and existing?

Comment: I think you have not extended ListActivity.You can try this tutorial [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/) it's easy to understand

Answer (score 5):

I think you haven't implemented OnItemClickListener

Try the below code

```
        //Declare your listView  here
        yourlistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {


                 Intent callActivity = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class); 
                 startActivity(callActivity);
                 }
            }); 
        }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: But the tutorial I am following, the person hasn't include setonitemclicklistener and still his program is working. Why is that

Comment: which tutorial u following.. I am not sure which you following but in my perspective this is one of the best way to achieve your goal.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjHYyAJQ7Vw&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A&index=21&feature=plpp_video
This is the tutorial which I am following. This guy is not using any listener method.

Comment: @AlfredJames If you extend `ListActivity` not just `Activity` and also give `"@id/android:list"` as id in your `ListView` declaration inside your layout xml, your approach will work, else only Vinoth approach can work.

Comment: I am not much familiar with the method you shown. If you could try this [tutorial](http://android-helper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/android-listview-onclick-ample.html) it will helpful for you and it really easy too.. Just add your intent in the place of alertDialog in the tutorial.